# Create a new file and Cats in a header from a file

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to make a bash script that takes the user input for the file name and adds a tag, .cpp ; .hpp ; or .app to the end of the file. In addition, the new file created will automatically add a header into the file from a separate file called header.txt

Some Sudo Code I have so far is:

## Asks user for file name

echo filename

## asks which tag

1 for .cpp

2 for .hpp

3 for .app

## Cats header.txt into filename.ext

cat filename.ext > header.txt

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
echo "Enter the file name"
read filename
echo "file tag: 1 for .cpp, 2 for .hpp, 3 for .app"
if [ "tag" = 1]; then
    filetag = .cpp
fi
if [ "tag" = 2];then
    filetag = .hpp
```

This is just the first part. Started learning Bash about a few days ago. Visualizing this part is what I confuse myself in trying to just create a file with user input file name.

Comment: post your bash script

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem. Please do so. If you run into difficulties, you can explain that difficulty, include the relevant portions of your code, and as a specific question, and we can try to help. See [ask]. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry it is a work in progress because I am learning bash.

Comment: To create a file, use the touch command. eg: touch "$filename$filetag"

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!

To copy the content of `header.txt` into the new file, do

```
cat header.txt > "$filename"
```

The final code will look like below.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                     
echo "Enter the file name"
read filename

echo "file tag: 1 for .cpp, 2 for .hpp, 3 for .app"
read tag
case $tag in 
"1")
    extension=".cpp"
    ;;
"2")
    extension=".hpp"
    ;;
"3")
    extension=".app"
    ;;
*)
    echo "Invalid option"
    exit
esac

filename="$filename$extension"

cat header.txt > "$filename"
```

Comment: so using Cat it is, cat (file that has the header) > (input operator) $filename (this is the file name we just created?)